# Unique values of the array with four fields

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I've an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    1 => array(1, 3, 2, 4),
    2 => array(1, 2, 4, 3),
    3 => array(1, 2, 5, 6)
)
```

I have to remove records that are repeated. So I need finally to have this array:

```
array(
    0 => array(1, 2, 3, 4),
    3 => array(1, 2, 5, 6)
)
```

The script is in PHP.

Who can help? :)

Comment: Have you tried with any code on your own? Show some effort at least.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying, but I'm doing additional loop to filtering. I wanna do it without loop.

Comment: @JakubKubera ^ Then show your work which you have done and your effort! Edit your question and add your code

Comment: @Uchiha OP will get a notification for *every* answer, which he gets, so no need for writing a comment, which goes under too chatty.

Comment: @Rizier123 I've deleted my comment. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just go through each sub array with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) the arrays. Then simply return them [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)'ed. With the created array you can just use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and then [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the values again.

```
<?php

    $result = array_map(function($v){
        return explode(",", $v);
    }, array_unique(array_map(function($v){
            sort($v);
            return implode(",", $v);
        }, $arr)));

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is

```
$filter = array();
$result = array_filter($array, function($e) use (&$filter) {
    $sum = array_sum($e);
    $ret = isset($filter[$sum]);
    $filter[$sum] = true;

    return !$ret;
});
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/9H60L)

Answer (score 0):

This must be the easy to understand

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    sort($value);
    $arr[$key] = $value;
}
$result = array_unique($arr,SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 6
        )

)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/372436)